# ¿Cómo pasar componentes como parámetros en React?

Tags: reactjs

Necesito pasar como parámetro un componente para que se renderize desde otro componente.

En el siguiente ejemplo quiero renderizar *Titulo1* o *Titulo2* dentro de *Perfil*

Dados los componentes:

```
export class Titulo1 extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (<div><H2>this.props.nombre</H2><h3>this.props.apellido</H3></div>)
  }
}

export class Titulo2 extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (<div><H1>this.props.nombre</H1><h2>this.props.apellido</H2></div>)
  }
}
```

y

```
export class Perfiles extends React.Component {
  render () {
   let perfiles= this.props.usuarios.map((usuario, index, coll) => {
        var props = {
          id: usuario.id,
          index: index,
          apellido: usuario.apellido,
          nombre: usuario.nombre
        }
         return (<Perfil {...props}>
            {React.createElement(this.props.extraComponent, props)}
          </Perfil>)
      }, this)
    }
    return ({perfiles})
  }
}

   export class Perfil extends React.Component {
      render () {
        return (<div><H2>this.props.id</H2>{this.props.children}</div>)
      }
    }
```

el objetivo es llamar a

```
<Perfiles extraComponent={Titulo1} usuarios={lista} />
```

o

```
<Perfiles extraComponent={Titulo2} usuarios={lista} />
```

según se necesite, pero no me deja me da error en `React.createElement(this.props.extraComponent, props)`.

¿Alguna sugerencia? 
¡¡muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¿Para qué llamas a `createElement`? ¿No te basta con `<Perfil>{ this.props.extraComponent }</Perfil>`?

Comment: Necesito pasar "props" como parametro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías probar con

```
<this.props.extraComponent {...props} />
```

El valor que pasas en el prop `extraComponent` es un Component como tal, por lo tanto puedes usarlo con sintaxis de JSX.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, gracias!

Comment: Esto esta en contra el diseño de React al pasar componentes directamente en props y utilizando esa variable como un literal en la definición del componente... es un pésimo diseño, jamas hagas eso.

Answer (score 2):

Hay dos técnicas para esto: composición y herencia, React utiliza composición, mira la [documentación](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html), un ejemplo donde se utiliza herencia es Swing en Java o Android.

Centrándonos en React la implementación es la siguiente

```
export class Perfiles extends React.Component {
    ...
    render () {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

posteriormente utilizas tu componente de la siguiente manera

```
<Perfiles usuarios={lista} />
    <Titulo nombre="Jose Maria" apellido="Toscano"/>
</Perfiles>
```